# how to add image file or base64 address to http post request?

Tags: javascript, http, post

I copied the post information through my PHP page.
The only problem is how I add the audio link to the post request?
I want later to send the post through js

Request Headers:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:80/in.php

Host: 127.0.0.1:80
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------134852597824187
Content-Length: 8442
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

Request Body:

```
-----------------------------134852597824187
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image2.png"
Content-Type: image/png

'Here I see a long address to the picture, but it's a tricky address, would it be possible to add base64?

‰PNG
pœËÖ¶ÁÁñDB°ýØêê2ŽsÒi¦è†‘...

-----------------------------134852597824187
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="method"

post
-----------------------------134852597824187
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imacros"

true
-----------------------------134852597824187--
```

PHP CODE:

```
<form id="host" method=post action="http://127.0.0.1:80/in.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="post">
<input type="hidden" name="imacros" value="true">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: There's a question here, but I can't quite see it. Where's the PHP and/or JavaScript code?

Comment: @tadman I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I believe file upload using javascript requires some work. I suggest you try [jQuery-File-Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) which is an excellent library for handling file uploads in javascript.